# Parameter declaration in Procedure Prototype and Interface in RPG

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I am trying to understand the way parameter variables are declared in Procedure Prototype (PR) and Procedure Interface (PI) in an RPG program. Why is it that the parameter variables need to be defined in both the PR and PI? Declaring it both places is necessary but why the need to redefine?

Comment: Yep.  That's the way IBM made it.  I think they had COBOL on their brain where the procedure is also defined in two places.

Comment: ANSI C has also previously used declarations of both prototypes and interfaces. The prototype is intended to be used by callers and the interface is used by the called procedure. A caller needs to know the proper data forms the are expected, and the called proc needs to know what's going to come from a caller. Since the two are often in different programs, two separate definitions are needed because forms must match on both sides of a call. The usual question is why both are needed in a single, stand-alone ILE RPG program, and the answer is that that's true only for non-current releases.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need a `Dcl-Pr` for procedures within the same module. You only need a prototype for procedures which are either

1. within a different module within the program
2. in a service program which you are trying to reference

Comment: This assumes the OP is on and compiling for a recent version of the OS.  Older versions required the PR even for the module's internal procedures.

Comment: I generally define a procedure interface for programs now as well instead of using `*ENTRY PLIST`. While it is not necessary to define a prototype for these, it does make calls a bit nicer because I put all of my prototypes in a separate copy book, and I can just copy in the appropriate prototypes when I need to call the program.

Comment: Yes it's very useful in service programs. You just put the prototype of your procedure in the calling program and then you can use the procedure of the service programs (when the procedure is defined with 'EXPORT').